# Forwarding arguments to functions in Python in a way explicit for a language server

Tags: python, python-typing

Consider composing functions together and adding new documentation:

```py
def comp_fun(*a, **ks):
    '''This f1's, f2's, f3's the ...'''
    return f3(f2(f1(*a, **ks)))
```

and having it properly recognized by autocompletion software, showing the arguments of `f1` and their types.

Another example:

```py
from toolz import compose # Couldn't find anything equivalent in std?

TTMSpecialCase = compose(TypeTakingModel, SpecialCaseModel)
```

and have `TTMSpecialCase` conveniently discovered by language servers and similar tools.

Is there any pattern (using stdlib stuff?) that's recognized by tools to do this?

Comment: functools wraps decorator?

Comment: @DanD. Ah. Forgot all about that. It gets one most of the way there. But it considers the entire 'head' of the signature (name and args, but not return type) from the wrapped function. The only thing missing is to take the name and doc from the 'wrapping' function. The main difference, I think, is that the case here is about extending an API with a normal member, not wrapping a member with transparent functionality (which `wraps` works for). Please let me know if I didn't clarify well.